# BFS: PriorityQueue not getting empty

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue, breadth-first-search, java-8

So I want to solve the problem described in my last post: [Terrain/Mountain algorithm not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478811/terrain-mountain-algorithm-not-working-as-intended). A copy of the problem is the following:

I want to create a terrain with a mountain on it, using a very basic principle, shown by this height mapping:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It starts at a random point with `height = 4`, and then gradually decreases it amonst the neighbours.

The recursive idea is simple, I start a point, recurse to the top/down/left/right with `height - 1` (in this example), and only if not encountered yet, I set their values.

So I went ahead and implemented it with a BFS:

```
private void createMountain(final float[][] heightMapping, final float startHeight) {
    boolean[][] traversed = new boolean[width][depth];
    boolean positive = (startHeight >= 0f);
    int x = random.nextInt(width);
    int z = random.nextInt(depth);
    PriorityQueue<QueueElement> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> (int)Math.signum(o1.height - o2.height));
    priorityQueue.offer(new QueueElement(x, z, startHeight));
    while (!priorityQueue.isEmpty()) {
        QueueElement current = priorityQueue.poll();
        if (current.x < 0 || current.x >= width || current.z < 0 || current.z >= depth) {
            continue;
        }
        if (traversed[current.x][current.z]) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((positive && current.height <= 0f) || (!positive && current.height >= 0f)) {
            continue;
        }
        heightMapping[x][z] = current.height;
        priorityQueue.offer(new QueueElement(x, z - 1, calculateNewHeight(current.height, positive)));
        priorityQueue.offer(new QueueElement(x, z + 1, calculateNewHeight(current.height, positive)));
        priorityQueue.offer(new QueueElement(x - 1, z, calculateNewHeight(current.height, positive)));
        priorityQueue.offer(new QueueElement(x + 1, z, calculateNewHeight(current.height, positive)));
    }
}

private class QueueElement {
    public int x, z;
    public float height;

    public QueueElement(final int x, final int z, final float height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

private float calculateNewHeight(final float startHeight, final boolean positive) {
    float delta = startHeight / maxDecayFactor;
    return (positive) ? startHeight - delta : startHeight + delta;
}
```

Now the code never stops, I tried debugging it a few times, but either got no useful result, or a terrain that was completely flat.

The only real clue I have currently is that the `priorityQueue.size()` keeps increasing by 3 the whole time.
Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

**Update**: Even after the fixes, it is still not working as intended.

```
0.6  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.8  1.0  1.2  1.6  1.9  2.4  3.0  3.8  4.7  5.9  7.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

What could possibly be wrong? Is the `PriorityQueue` now messing things up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set `traversed[x][z] = true;` when you poll a new element.

Make sure you do it AFTER you query `if (traversed[current.x][current.z]) ...`

Also, as a side note, for your implementation - a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) will be a better idea I think. (when I wrote a PriorityQueue will be better I had multiple peaks in mind - which seems not to be the case for you, I think a simple Queue will be best).

Comment: I was relocating the `traversed[x][z] = true` and forgot to put it back. But actually more things were wrong, I now added an epsilon value and also I needed to use `current.x` and `current.z` in most occasions, and not the initial `x` and `z`! The only problem I have now, is that the terrain still looks wrong, I'll add extra output to the OP.

Comment: With using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` it now suddenly works! I yet have no clue though why it didn't work with a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: @skiwi what did you put as a comparator function to the priority queue?

Comment: `PriorityQueue<QueueElement> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> (int)Math.signum(o1.height - o2.height));`, which is using lambdas shorthand for maximum first.

Comment: @skiwi I think it happened because you chagned `o2.height` for objects that are already in the priority queue (deeper in it) - which resulted in this behavior, but I could be wrong.

Comment: A priority queue actually just violates the whole purpose of using a queue, nwo I think about it.